# C# Populating treeview with pdf files

Tags: c#, treeview

In my Winforms application i created a treeview to show all folders of a certain project, this is working great but i also want to be able to see the pdf files stored in the folders.

Here is my code i use to obtain the folder structure of a certain project.

```
void PopulateTree()
    {
        //Getting the correct location for the project
            TreeNode rootnode = new TreeNode(@"Z:\Projecten\" + slctJaarBox.Text + "\\" + slctProjectBox.Text);
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootnode);
            FillChildNodes(rootnode);
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Expand();

    }


    void FillChildNodes(TreeNode node)
    {
        //Creates the nodes for the folder structure on root level
        try
        {
            FileInfo files = new FileInfo(node.FullPath);

            DirectoryInfo dirs = new DirectoryInfo(node.FullPath);
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs.GetDirectories())
            {
                TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode(dir.Name);
                node.Nodes.Add(newnode);
                newnode.Nodes.Add("*");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void treeView1_BeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //Will only load and add a node subdirectorys if a node is expanded, 
        //this is for faster loading
        if (e.Node.Nodes[0].Text == "*")
        {
            e.Node.Nodes.Clear();
            FillChildNodes(e.Node);
        }
    }
```

Got it working, it is probally not the best way.

```
void FillChildNodes(TreeNode node)
    {
        try
        {

            DirectoryInfo dirs = new DirectoryInfo(node.FullPath);
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs.GetDirectories())
            {
                TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode(dir.Name);
                node.Nodes.Add(newnode);
                newnode.Nodes.Add("*");

            }

            FileInfo[] arrFilesInFolder = null;
            FileInfo bestandInFolder = null;

            arrFilesInFolder = dirs.GetFiles("*.pdf");
            foreach (FileInfo fileInFolder_loopVariable in arrFilesInFolder)
            {
                bestandInFolder = fileInFolder_loopVariable;
                TreeNode newnode = new TreeNode(bestandInFolder.Name);
                node.Nodes.Add(newnode);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your problem? what have you tried? where did it fail? and how did it fail?

Comment: My problem is how i can do the same thing for pdf files, got the folder structure working but didn't find out yet how to do this for files and place them in the correct node.

Comment: Got it working, edited my question with an anwser.

Comment: you don't need this line `bestandInFolder = fileInFolder_loopVariable;` and can delete `bestandInFolder`alltogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing from your update here's an example of how I would do it. It does not do exactly the same as your code. I've put the file nodes as sub nodes to the directory because I feel that's more intuitive but changing it back to what you have shouldn't be to difficult if that's the functionality you are looking for

```
public TreeNode[] CreateChildNodes(){
      return (from directory in Directory.GetDirectories(node.FullPath)
             let directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(directory)
             let pdfFiles = from file in Directory.GetFiles(directory,"*.pdf")
                            select new TreeNode(Path.GetFileName(file))
             select new TreeNode(directoryName,pdfFiles.ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

A few things to note; Since you're only using the name of the files and directories I don't think there's any idea in instantiating DirectoryInfo or FileInfo objects so I've changed that to simply use paths/strings. I also prefer helper functions such as this to be sideeffect free which is why I return a collection of nodes rather than attach them to the node passed in in your version (you can call node.Nodes.AddRange passing in the result which is the reason why the method returns an array and not an IEnumerable)